# I'm confused with the uses of the words such as "so that", "in order to", and "to"

Tags: grammar

> 1. Meat and vegetables are prepacked before they are sold so that they will be hygienic.
> 2. Meat and vegetables are prepacked before they are sold in order to be hygienic.
> 3. Meat and vegetables are prepacked before they are sold to be hygienic.
> 4. Before they are sold, meat and vegetables are prepacked to be hygienic.

I'd like to know whether they have the same meaning. And which adverbials should be used? In the sentence 2 and 3, I'm comfused with the places of "in order to ..." and " to-infinitive"
In the sentence 1 and 2, adverbials are "so that they will be hygienic" and "in order to be hygienic". Is it correct to use them? In the sentence 3 and 4, what is the grammatical function of "to-infinitive"?

Comment: @theinIwin Your question about "adverbials" is unclear, and “such as” does not appear in your question! Your dictionary tells you what “such as”, “so that”, “in order to”, and “to” mean, and how they are used in English. What dictionary have you consulted? What do you not understand about those definitions? There is good advice [**here**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  about asking a good question.

Comment: @theinIwin  Your question is still unclear. What "adverbials" do you refer to? What do you not understand about "so that, "in order that," and "to"?

Comment: In the sentence 1 and 2, adverbials are "so that they will be hygienic" and "in order to be hygienic". Is it correct to use them? In the sentence 3 and 4, what is the grammatical function of "to-infinitive"?

Comment: @theinIwin These comments belong in your question. Use the [`edit`](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/102187/edit) link under your question to add them!